# keyword user id not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services

We have a windows service based application which connects to database using entity framework.And we were using the below connection string to access, which was working fine. All of a sudden its throwing the exception "keyword user id not supported". I have tried various options by adding providerName, removing provider etc but still no luck. Any guidance on this would be very helpful.

Connection String:

```
"metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=dbname;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;\"
```

Note: If i try to connect from my local machine and test, the connection doesnt seem to throw an exception.

Stack trace:

> 12/02 15:12:38.631  SubMessageType parse Exception: ArgumentException:Keyword not supported: 'user id'.
>   12/02 15:12:39.224     at System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName).. code reference

Update: there was a additional quotes that was added that was causing the issue, noticed that when i was changing the quotes to ". Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Can you [edit] and include the full stack trace?

Comment: @DavidG It should be a link like "Let Me Start Editing Your Question For You" ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Unfortunately it's just what the `[edit]` autolink gives us!

Comment: @DavidG No, I mean it would be great that it would be something like LMGTFY

Comment: DO NOT put "solved" in your title You mark an answer solved by accepting a  answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue might be the escaped double quotes halfway through the connection string.

Change those to `&quot;` and it should work:

```
"metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=dbname;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;&quot;"
```

Comment: Keyword not supported: 'data source' is the exception that i am getting.

Comment: Hi, thank you this worked too, but had to decode the string before making the connection